# for loop in a list of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

new programmer here. I was trying to do a for loop through a bunch of dataframes so that I can create new columns without having it repeat myself multiple times.

So I created a few of these:

```
premarket = master_df[(master_df['time'] >= '04:01:00') & (master_df['time'] <= '09:30:00') & (master_df['volume'] > 0)]
```

Obviously with different times and tied to different names as you will see in a second. Then I tried to loop through that list but kept getting an error. This is what I tried:

```
for timezone in timezones:
    statdf[f'{timezone} high'] = timezone.high.max()

Attribute Error: 'str' object has no attribute 'high'
```

I also tried:

```
timezones = list(intraday, morningopen, morning, morningmid, midday, afternoon)

for timezone in timezones:
    statdf[f'{timezone} high'] = timezone.high.max()

TypeError: list expected at most 1 argument, got 6
```

What do I do to fix it and where can I read or watch videos more about it?

Comment: first you could use `print()`, `print(type(...))` to see what you have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"`. It seems `timezone` is a string but string doesn't have `.high` so you can't do `timezone.high`. You don't show how you create `timezones` and `intraday, morningopen, morning, morningmid, midday, afternoon` so we can't see what is the problem - and we can't help you

Comment: to create list you should use `[ ]` instead `list()` - or `list( [intraday, morningopen, morning, morningmid, midday, afternoon] )` but in this situation it is simpler to skip `list()` and keep only `[intraday, morningopen, morning, morningmid, midday, afternoon]`